# PHP SpagoBI SOAP Request

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have been searching for a sample of PHP code using SOAP to connect to SpagoBI4.1. Specifically, I am intersted in the headers that need to be set.

Currently, I am unable to connect to the SpagoBI Server with SOAP error of Security Header is not set. I have trawled a ton of forums, even bought their (useless) book, and sadly no luck.

I also worked through the huge number of different wsdl docs provided by SpagoBI and could not find any mention of headers that need to be set.

I sincerely hope that someone out there will be able to assist with a sample?

Many thanks

Comment: I can give you some help..I was working on it as well and I am completely agree with you...The only one open source BI platform that you can use freely is without documentation..just some videos on youtube from only one/two person and all different information is on different books (obsolete until now because they are in the version 5 and the book is for 3)..I am thinking that there are some marketing tactical behind getting training for their customer..I mean is so f.. difficult to start..Basically, I would ask you what you are waiting to do from ws.. Is it to get chart, reports, etc from ws?